# Always vertically center content of a textarea input

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm working on a small project where textarea are used.

And the problem with textarea is that the text always start at the top left corner...

And what i want is to have the content inside of that textarea always centered. And then if I add a line it'll expend from the middle, something like this :

[image: 1 line]
[image: 2 lines]

I looked for thing like vertical align and thing like that, but i also saw things about inserting a div... But i was wondering if there was a solution with textarea

Thanks !

Comment: So the last line should be in the middle?

Comment: Not neceserally, like it expend from the _middle_... And so, if we have something like 3 lines, the 2nd line will be in the middle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can align the text in `textarea` vertically, but you can fake it!

**HTML and CSS:**

1. Create a resizable `div`
2. Nest a `contenteditable` `p` in that `div`
3. Add a `placeholder` for the `p` when it's empty
4. Use `flexbox` to set the `p` in the middle: `align-items: center;`
5. Add `p {white-space: pre-line;}` to prevent the `overflow` when typing
6. Add `p {outline: 0px solid transparent;}` to remove the border on focus

**JavaScript:**

1. Get the target (`p`)
2. Add an `event` on `keypress`
3. Check for pressing `Enter`
4. Prevent the `default event` and insert a line break (new line) instead
5. Add an `event` on `click` to the `div` to focus the `p` (textarea behavior)

```js
// Get the target
let p = document.querySelector('p');
let div = document.querySelector('div');

// Add event onkeypress
p.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
  let keyCode = e.code || e.key;
  // Check for pressing 'Enter'
  if(keyCode === 'Enter') {
    // Prevent the default event and insert line break (new line) instead
    document.execCommand('insertLineBreak');
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});

// Add event onclick 
div.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Focus on p to get the textarea behavior
  p.focus();
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
    resize: both;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 30px auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: text;
}

p {
  white-space: pre-line;
  width: 100%;
  height: fit-content;
  outline: 0px solid transparent;
}

p:empty::before {
    content: attr(placeholder);
    color: #666666; 
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p contenteditable="true" placeholder="Type here..."></p>
</div>
```

Comment: It breaks when you press enter

Comment: It's great, but it's not working when you press enter (even if i can block the enter click if there are no others ways) and also is that possible to remove the border arround the <p> ?